# How to print/log address of a variable in NDK

Tags: android, c, logging, android-ndk

I'm not very strong in C, but I'm working with the NDK right now and I need help logging address of a variable in hex. I've been using `__android_log_print` to print generic log messages, but how do I tell C to convert address of a variable to a char array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I never worked with android NDK, but I'm assuming `__android_log_print` works with printf format characters. In that case you may use `%p`.

Let's say we have a variable `int a =  10;`. To print its address:

```
printf("%p\n", &a); //This will print in hexadecimal
```

**EDIT**:

Accepted answer:

```
__android_log_print(SOME_PRIO, "sometag", "%p", &a);
```

Comment: Yep, but `__android_log_print` does not have formatting like `printf` does, so I need to actually convert an address to string before passing it to this function.

Comment: Ok, I got a quick look at the documentation and thought one could do something like ``__android_log_print(SOME_PRIO, "sometag", "%p", &a);``, sorry then.

Comment: No idea how I missed that. Thanks = )

Answer (score 2):

I work with Android NDK many times and I have tried before use native logcat.

```
__android_log_print(6, "deneme", "text"); -> this is error message
typedef enum android_LogPriority {
ANDROID_LOG_UNKNOWN = 0,
ANDROID_LOG_DEFAULT,    /* only for SetMinPriority() */
ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,
ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,
ANDROID_LOG_INFO,
ANDROID_LOG_WARN,
ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,
ANDROID_LOG_FATAL,
ANDROID_LOG_SILENT,     /* only for SetMinPriority(); must be last */
} android_LogPriority;
```

and than include header in c source files

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
```

than makefile look like

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := deneme-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := deneme.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog  

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```